# app fails to talk to server when in test mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an iphone app talking to a local dev server (rails). I plug the phone into the mac that's running Xcode. Both the mac and the phone are on the same wifi. I can run the app fine, but it can't connect to my dev server.

I can confirm that the phone can hit the test server by typing: http://192.168.1.30:3000 into a web browser on the phone.

But when the app itself tries to issue a request I get this:

```
Task <6B0D8F2F-CB2F-4913-AC56-4789AFE979EE>.<1> finished with error [-1009] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x302e05b00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=unsatisfied (Local network prohibited), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, uses wifi, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6B0D8F2F-CB2F-4913-AC56-4789AFE979EE>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6B0D8F2F-CB2F-4913-AC56-4789AFE979EE>.<1>"
),
```

So I'm guessing it has to do with this "local network prohibited...uses wifi" error message. Presumably something is configured to disallow this kind of thing. Is there a way to turn this off?

Running Xcode 15.3, the mac is running sonoma 14.4, and the iphone is at 17.4

Edit: I did find something that talked about how the user on the phone needs to grant the permission. To get this to happen: delete the app, rerun it, and the permission popup should be seen. Sure enough this did happen, I said "allow app to connect to devices on the local network", but I still get the same problem.